# How to include mousewhell scroll and click event in the if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I manage that if the user scrolls down the mouse wheel or clicks on `$('#next')` it will execute the function below?

```
var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
if (wd < 0 || $("#next").click(function() {}) {
    if (status == 1 && $('body').scrollTop() == $("#b1").offset().top) {
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#b2").offset().top
        }, 900);
        prev.style.display = "block";
        b1Slide_b('b1');
        b1Slide('b2');
        status = 2;
    }
```

Comment: Could add a bit more explanation of what you are trying to do. Your code is a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Include the code you want executed in a function, and then initiate both event to point to that function:

```
function stuffToDo(){
 // the stuff you want to do here
}
$("#next").click(function() {
  stuffToDo();
}
$("#next").scroll(function() {
  stuffToDo();
}
```

This is not the cleanest way but it will allow you to give custom parameters to your function depending on the event, if you need.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try something like this with your code.

made and example : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/gq34h3vL/)**

```
function myFunc() {
 $(".content").css({"background":"red"})

};
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop()>0) {
   myFunc();
  };
});
$(".trigger").click(function(){
   myFunc();
});
```

you need to do 2 separate functions in which you callback your function .
in `myFunc()` you insert everything you want to happen `on scroll` or `on click`
in this case changing the background color